# Kernel debug output not shown in DebugView ( Win7 x64 )

Tags: kernel, windows-7-x64, debugview

I'm using DebugView 4.78 to debug output from my driver. I've used the instructions from [here](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=295) (option 1, setting DEFAULT value to 0xf), rebooted, but I still cannot get any debug output from my driver (driver build is chk x64 win7).

Ideas?

Edit: I found the problem, the build process in one step is copying the new .sys file to the drivers location (C:\Windows\System32\drivers), however, even though the copy operations says  "1 file copied", I can see that the destination file is not updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Visual Studio is 32 bit, on a 64 bit Windows it is a WOW64 process. If such a process tries to write to `%WinDir%\System32\` the result will be redirected to `%WinDir%\SysWOW64`. By using the special alias *Sysnative*, you can write to `%WinDir%\Sysnative`, and then it will end up in `%WinDir%\System32\`, as intended.

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx).